# Google Maps API V3 TrafficLayer Widget

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

[Google Maps Traffic Widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8bIM.png)

i want to show the widget from the picture above in my embedded map to show typical traffic. but i can't seem to find any documentation for this. this is my current javascript code

```
 function initMap() {
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 17,
  clickableIcons: false,
  center: {lat: 34.04924594193164, lng: -118.24104309082031}

});

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: {lat: 34.04924594193164, lng: -118.24104309082031},
  map: map,
  title: 'myMarker',
  draggable: false
});

var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
trafficLayer.setMap(map);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exactly what  you want is not provided in official document.
You can create custom legends base on this [tutorial](http://pietervogelaar.nl/google-maps-api-v3-traffic-toggle-button)

```js
function initMap() {

  var options = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 34.04924594193164, lng: -118.24104309082031},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-container'), options);

//var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
//trafficLayer.setMap(map);
  var controlDiv = document.createElement('DIV');
$(controlDiv).addClass('gmap-control-container')
             .addClass('gmnoprint');
          
var controlUI = document.createElement('DIV');
$(controlUI).addClass('gmap-control');
$(controlUI).text('Traffic');
$(controlDiv).append(controlUI);
          
var legend = '<ul>'
           + '<li><span style="background-color: #30ac3e">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #30ac3e"> &gt; 80 km per hour</span></li>'
           + '<li><span style="background-color: #ffcf00">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #ffcf00"> 40 - 80 km per hour</span></li>'
           + '<li><span style="background-color: #ff0000">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #ff0000"> &lt; 40 km per hour</span></li>'
           + '<li><span style="background-color: #c0c0c0">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #c0c0c0"> No data available</span></li>'
           + '</ul>';
          
var controlLegend = document.createElement('DIV');
$(controlLegend).addClass('gmap-control-legend');
$(controlLegend).html(legend);
$(controlLegend).hide();
$(controlDiv).append(controlLegend);
          
// Set hover toggle event
$(controlUI)
    .mouseenter(function() {
        $(controlLegend).show();
    })
    .mouseleave(function() {
        $(controlLegend).hide();
    });
          
var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
          
google.maps.event.addDomListener(controlUI, 'click', function() {
    if (typeof trafficLayer.getMap() == 'undefined' || trafficLayer.getMap() === null) {
        $(controlUI).addClass('gmap-control-active');
        trafficLayer.setMap(map);
    } else {
        trafficLayer.setMap(null);
        $(controlUI).removeClass('gmap-control-active');
    }
});
          
map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(controlDiv);
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
 * element that contains the map. */
#map-container {
  height: 100%;
}
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.gmap-control-container {
    margin: 5px;
}
.gmap-control {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #FEFEFE, #F3F3F3);
    background-color: #FEFEFE;
    border: 1px solid #A9BBDF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    padding: 0 6px;
    line-height: 160%;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.gmap-control:hover {
    border: 1px solid #678AC7;
}
.gmap-control-active {
    background-color: -moz-linear-gradient(center top , #6D8ACC, #7B98D9);
    background-color: #6D8ACC;
    color: #fff;
    font-weight: bold;
    border: 1px solid #678AC7;
}
.gmap-control-legend {
    position: absolute;
    text-align: left;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 20px;
    right: 0;
    width: 150px;
    height: 66px;
    font-size: 10px;
    background: #FEFEFE;
    border: 1px solid #A9BBDF;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
}
.gmap-control-legend ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.gmap-control-legend li {
    line-height: 160%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="map-container"></div>

<!-- Replace the value of the key parameter with your own API key. -->
<script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap">
</script>
```

Comment: This answers the legend part and handles the toggle-able traffic layer. I don't think the typical traffic data is documented by the API itself yet. Thanks!